# Pauli matrices Measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, quantum-measurements

When performing a measurement On qubits with the Pauli matrices, They all correspond to outcomes +1,-1 because that's their eigenvalues? In my notes it says that the $z$ Pauli matrix can be broken down into projections or to density matrix one corresponding to + eigenvalue and the other corresponding to - eigenvalue. When I try and do something similar with the other Pauli matrices I'm confused as to how you decide which outcome +1 or -1 corresponds to which projection.

Comment: Do you understand the eigenvalue structure of an [arbitrary Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote spin up and spin down states (in $S_z$) basis as $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ respectively. Then $\sigma_z=|0\rangle \langle 0|-|1\rangle \langle 1|$ as you correctly pointed out (with $\sigma_z|0\rangle=|0\rangle$ and $\sigma_z|1\rangle=-|1\rangle$) .
Similarly the eigenstates for $\sigma_x$ given by
\begin{equation}
|+\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},|-\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}
with eigenvalues $+1,-1$ respectively (that is $\sigma_x|+\rangle=|+\rangle$ and $\sigma_x|-\rangle=-|-\rangle$) can be used to decompose $\sigma_x$ as
\begin{equation}
|+\rangle \langle +|-|-\rangle \langle -|=\left(\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{\langle0|+\langle 1|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\left(\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{\langle0|-\langle 1|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=|0\rangle \langle 1|+|1\rangle \langle 0|=\sigma_x
\end{equation}
For $\sigma_y$ follow the same procedure with its eigenstates given by,
\begin{equation}
|+i\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle+i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},|-i\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle-i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}
with eigenvalues $+1,-1$ respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, I can see now using the eigenvectors